# How to fit all the linear layouts one after the other in a relative layout so that it adjusts its height if more linear layouts are added

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im31"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im32"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im33"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im34"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im41"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im42"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im43"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im44"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im51"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im52"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im53"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im54"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/munshee_logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here the images in each row are not of the same size, also I have 5 linear layouts in the code but only 3 are visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6eKm.png)

I want the `linear layouts` to adjust their heights so that all the 5 `linear layouts` fit in the screen.

Comment: use linear layout for this it will work easily

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don't need to take `Relative Layout` as your `Root Layout`. Because you can do it with `Linear Layout` as `Root Layout`. With use of `Weight` property.

*Here is xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im31"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im32"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im33"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im34"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im41"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im42"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im43"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im44"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im51"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im52"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im53"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im54"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: that's correct, however, I'd delete the android:weightSum="5" line from the root layout, allowing android to calculate the correct sum dynamically whenever layouts are added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="5"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im11"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im12"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im13"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im14"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/layout2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1">
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im31"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im34"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im41"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im42"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im43"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im44"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im51"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im52"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im53"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im54"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the `android:layout_weight` lines from Relative and Linears layouts